# Redis query to find between ranges

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I'm working on a migration project, currently the data look-up is from an in-memory cache. We are switching to Redis in-memory cache , looking for a solution in Redis cache.

Right now in our table there are records with min and max values. The table column is as below

### Min    Max   vendor_name

### 1000   2000  VENDOR_1

### 2000   3000  VENDOR_2

Request from a client whose accoutNo is falling in between the range (Min - Max), from the above example if the client accountNo is **1500** then the response will be VENDOR_1. Min and max will be unique values there will not be duplicates, there will be millions of records in the DB for min-max (range) . I'm trying to insert these records in to Redis, went through redis documents and did some online reading. There are many references to redis ZRANGEBYSCORE but I could not finalize any solution. If anyone have implemented something similar in Redis please share. Highly appreciate .

I tried the below one, which did not give the desired result.

zadd 123456 999.1 vendor1  10000.1 vendor2 10010.1 vendor3 15000.1 vendor4 16000.1 vendor5

zrangebyscore 123456 16000 +inf limit 0 1
"vendor5"

Comment: Why 1500 is VENDOR_2?

Comment: @YilunZhang - Sorry my bad, it will be VENDOR_1